# Don't repeat posts from children in parent taxonomy query

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, children

I have a query on a page and I want to prevent it from returning posts in the parent term that have one of the child terms of the parent. For example:

Parent 1

Child 1

- Post 1
- Post 2

NOT

Parent 1

- Post 1
- Post 2

Child 1

- Post 1
- Post 2

Here's the query I'm currently using, but I haven't figured out how to prevent repetition of posts at the parent level.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'seo_resource_topics';
// Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
foreach( $terms as $term ) : 
  echo '<h3>'. $term->name. '</h3>';

  $resourcequery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'seo_resource',
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'term' => $term->slug,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

if( $resourcequery->have_posts() ): while( $resourcequery->have_posts() ) : $resourcequery->the_post(); 
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your post have always children and parent category you can just skip the query for parent using `continue`:

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) :
  echo '<h3>'. $term->name. '</h3>'; 
  if ( $term->parent == 0 ) continue;
  // rest of your code here
```

Problem whith this is only that if a post has a parent term, but doesn't have any children term you'll never see that post.

Comment: Wonderful. Many thanks. I have no trouble enforcing that all posts have to be in the child categories (they were anyway).